# .NET Maui ListView Get Currently visible items in Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, .net, xamarin, maui

I have a cross platform app (iOS/Android) currently built in Xamarin that needs to know which items in a list view are currently visible.  It is working in Xamarin, but I can't seem to figure out how to port it to Maui.  Does such a thing not require platform specific code in Maui?

Here are the relevant android/ios pieces I had in Xamarin

Android:

```
List<ViewerItemViewModel> visibleItems = new List<ViewerItemViewModel>();
try
{
    var renderer = lv.GetRenderer();

    var nativeListView = renderer.View as Android.Widget.ListView;

    for (int i = 0; i < nativeListView.ChildCount; i++)
    {
        var view = nativeListView.GetChildAt(i);

        if (view.Visibility != ViewStates.Visible)
            continue;

        int pos = nativeListView.GetPositionForView(view);

        if (pos < 0 || pos == AdapterView.InvalidPosition || pos >= nativeListView.Adapter.Count)
            continue;

        var obj = nativeListView.Adapter.GetItem(pos);

        if (obj == null)
            continue;

        ViewerItemViewModel visibleElement = Cast<ViewerItemViewModel>(obj);

        if (visibleElement != null && !visibleItems.Contains(visibleElement))
            visibleItems.Add(visibleElement);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {

}

return visibleItems;
```

iOS:

```
var visibleItems = new List<ViewerItemViewModel>();

var array = lv.ItemsSource.OfType<ViewerItemViewModel>();
var renderer = lv.GetRenderer();

UITableView nativeListView = (UITableView)renderer.NativeView;

NSIndexPath[] index = nativeListView.IndexPathsForVisibleRows;

if (index != null)
    for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
        if (index[i].Row >= 0 && index[i].Row < array.Count())
            visibleItems.Add(array.ElementAt(index[i].Row));

return visibleItems;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you may write some platform specific code, but Maui [Handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/?view=net-maui-8.0) make this quite easy. You could get access to the native view by using `myListView.Handler.PlatformView`. Also, this official docs may be helpful, [Invoke platform code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-8.0)

Just small changes with your code,

```
#if IOS
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
#elif ANDROID
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
#endif


...

    private void GetVisibleItems()
    {

        var myListView = lv as Microsoft.Maui.Controls.ListView;
        var visibleItems = new List<ViewerItemViewModel>();
        var array = myListView.ItemsSource.OfType<ViewerItemViewModel>();
#if IOS
        UITableView nativeListView = myListView.Handler.PlatformView as UITableView;

        NSIndexPath[] index = nativeListView.IndexPathsForVisibleRows;

        if (index != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < index.Length; i++)
                if (index[i].Row >= 0 && index[i].Row < array.Count())
                    visibleItems.Add(array.ElementAt(index[i].Row));

#elif ANDROID
        var nativeListView = myListView.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Widget.ListView;

        for (int i = 0; i < nativeListView.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var view = nativeListView.GetChildAt(i);

            if (view.Visibility != ViewStates.Visible)
                continue;

            int pos = nativeListView.GetPositionForView(view);

            if (pos < 0 || pos == AdapterView.InvalidPosition || pos >= nativeListView.Adapter.Count)
                continue;

            var obj = nativeListView.Adapter.GetItem(pos);

            if (obj == null)
                continue;

            ViewerItemViewModel visibleElement = Cast<ViewerItemViewModel>(obj);

            if (visibleElement != null && !visibleItems.Contains(visibleElement))
                visibleItems.Add(visibleElement);
        }

#endif

        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I ended up stumbling onto an answer after enough google searches.  My code ended up pretty much identical to what you have posted here.  Can confirm it works at least in Android!